# How do I teach my cat to stop biting after rough play?

Tags: cats, biting

My cat is always biting a family member. He(family member) has always been rough with the cat and my cat enjoys it. But recently she(my cat) has gotten more rough whilst he wants to stop roughhousing with her. She has occasionally draw blood as she tends to bite him harder.

As that he tend to get angry when she bites, she will now run away in anticipation of him getting angry, but will still continue to bite him.

What can I/that family member do to stop her from biting or let her know that he doesn't want to play this "game" anymore?

Comment: Related: [How do I discourage my cat from biting?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-discourage-my-cat-from-biting). Not a duplicate because of the roughhousing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop using his hands to play with the cat, the cat relates his hands with rough playtime, so you need to provide the cat with something else to play with. Until the cat disassociates your family member's hands with rough play I'd recommend a toy that has an extension.

Answer (score 2):

Cats are individuals.  I once had a cat that I could easily play who's-got-who with.  At least 80% of the time she would just wrap her forepaws around my wrist and gently mouth at my knuckles.  If she escalated, I could just give out an "Ouch!" and she let go.  She was probably thinking, "dat hooman such crybaby" but so what?  With my latest cat, he is simply too aggressive, so for the foreseeable future who's-got-who is out.

We have a different game instead.  I have a kiddie fishing pole with a bird toy tied in where a lure would be.  I need to be careful he doesn't tangle himself in the line, but I can cast down the hallway and reel him in for a half-hour at a time.  I get tired before he does.  I give this just as an example alternative- your mileage may vary.