# How do I stop my blind kitten from biting/clawing living things?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, biting, sight

I’ve trained many cats and kittens, but I recently adopted a new challenge, that’s proved to be, well, a bit of a challenge.

I’ve adopted two kittens, brothers, and one is a special needs cat: he is blind. They are currently 5 months old. The not-blind one is learning quickly, but the blind one is proving more difficult to train, especially when it comes to clawing and biting. The kitty does not discriminate between toys, hands, toes, other body parts and objects. Everything has to be explored by chewing on it and feeling it (with claws).

I’ve tried the technique mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/16/12491) but it doesn’t work, probably due to his handicap and his need for exploring. Still, I don’t like being bitten/clawed. How can I teach a visually impaired kitten the difference between living things and objects and that it’s not okay to bite them, without punishing him for trying to explore?

Comment: I'm trying a new tactic. I ordered catnip stuffed toys from the internet (will be a few days till they get here). I'll report back later.

Comment: I am going through the same thing. Love my little blind Manx kitten, but he nips on my legs when he wants attention and is nipping my little dog who he loves, but dog is getting testy about it. Some firm answers requested for those of us with blind kittens.

Comment: going through the same conundrum now. Were you able to train this out of your kitty? What worked?

Comment: @sotta I don't really have anything good enough to write an answer. I kept using the same techniques as in the answer, but it never really stopped. He still explores with his claws. We adapted to playing differently with him, rather than training him out of it.

Comment: @Belle How did you end up playing with him? I've just adopted a mostly blind kitten (she was found in the road and is only about 6 weeks old so teething too) I'm trying to bond with her so she doesn't feel lonely being so young - my older cats want nothing to do with her (1yr, 1.5yr, & 3 yrs) - but I am very hesitant to let her use me as a full-access chew toy.
I have toys that make noise so she can play with them, but she just loves to bite and chew anything and everything but especially me. Other kittens I've had, had eachother to chew on and learn good behaviour from, but I'm a bit stumped

Comment: Here is a youtube channel by a lady with a blind cat. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnyPPeqcs0k